# Get the dump of postgresql extension

Tags: pg-dump, postgresql-9.6

### 1. Is it possible to get the dump of the Postgresql extension?

- I have an extension under development which hypothetically sits on a production server and a lot of scripts like `ext_name--1.0.1--1.0.2.sql`.
- Is there a way, how to get the final version of the extension without manually writing the script file `ext_name--1.0.2.sql`?

For example in file `ext_name--1.0.0--1.0.1.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id integer, name text);
```

and in file `ext_name--1.0.1--1.0.2.sql`:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN city text;
```

will result in a code like from a dump (in file `ext_name--1.0.2.sql`):

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id integer, name text, city text);
```

`pg_dump` wold normally ignore the extension objects. I have only found a solution for including the extensions data (`pg_extension_config_dump()`).

### 2. Why the update scripts doesn't accept

```
COPY foo(id, name) FROM stdin;
```

command. I though this would be passed into psql, but psql will run it successfully. Do I have to always write inserts to get the data into extension?

### 3. Is there a solution for the update scripts to include files?

Like in pure psql through the `\i` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some time spent with the extension:

1. Yes it is. You can drop the ***member_object*** from an extension
   (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterextension.html) the object will then behave like usuall and will be registered by **pg_dump**.
2. Well, yeah, **no COPY**. But the pg_dump can accept parameter **--column-inserts** and then existing data (even quite large) can be translated into inserts within text dump, which was exactly what I needed (convert existing tables into extension install script).
3. I didn't find a solution to this but doesn't actually suit for what we needed. It is quite good to have functions in git stored separately to nicely see the changes in code. Solution for us is to duplicate it (first in a separate file, second in the extension change script so the extension can walk through versions without inspecting git history).